# Using certifi in urllib3

Tags: python, certificate, ssl-certificate, urllib3

I am new to python programming. Can anybody please tell if there will be any problem in fetching data from the web if I don't use certifi or any sort of certificate verification while using urllib3? I am getting warnings regarding the authenticity but data is fetched regardless of that. I was just wondering, if there is any possibility of any sort of error from any site. Also, does , not using certifi speed up data fetching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you forego verifying your HTTPS requests, then you have no way to verify that you're not a victim of a [Man-In-The-Middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) (and possibly other attacks). In effect, it would be equivalent to making an HTTP request (rather than HTTPS) in terms of security. If the data you're dealing with is not important, then that sacrifice could be okay.

In terms of performance ramifications, the difference should be very tiny especially compared to the network round trip in the first place. I would not consider it a factor.

Our [Security Section](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html) has more details on your various options, including how to disable the warnings.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The data I am dealing with is not at all that important that somebody will attempt a man-in-the-middle attack.

Comment: @xeon You're welcome. Honestly, I would recommend always verifying HTTPS just because it's a good habit to get into. :) You'll never regret verifying, but you might regret not verifying someday.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Actually the thing is am am doing anything and everything to make the application go faster. So, I need to cut every weight that weighs it down. Besides, the application fetches static data from public web pages, which no one needs to hack coz it's freely available.. Thanks for the suggestion though :)